# What is the project directory structure for a standalone Java SE application?

Tags: java, deployment, software-packaging

What is the standard project directory structure of a standalone Java SE (Command Line based) application?

`src` folder will contain all my `.java` files in properly organized packages. Other than that I have `bin` folder which will contain my `.class` files.

I've Properties files and XML configuration files in my project. In which directory should I place them? Should I create a package named `com.myproject.config` and place all the `.xml` config files in that?

I want the dependent jars to be packaged along with my final package. So should I create a folder (say by the name `lib`) to hold all these `.jar` files?

Comment: You may do as you describe. There is no constraint nor better accepted way.

Comment: A lot of this depends on which build tool/IDE you are using.  Note that if packaging it all up yourself, it is theoretically possible to use almost any structure, while an IDE will typically set up a structure that it more commonly uses.  As to *"create a package named com.myproject.config"*  Yes, that seems reasonable.

Comment: I think use Maven to build your project is a good option.

Comment: BTW - is this question really more about how to **deploy** the built application to the end-user?  What type of application is it?  (e.g. Desktop, command line, something meant for the system tray..?)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Command Line application

Comment: I edited 'command line' into the question, but am still not clear on the answer to my first question. *"is this question really more about how to **deploy** the built application to the end-user?"*   If not it seems the answer to this is 'use whatever structure that works for you'.

Answer (score 29):

I would recommend to stick with default [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) layout ( and also use maven as build tool )

Productive classes / resources:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
```

Test data and classes:

```
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

Maven can also take care to package your application properly with all the necessary jars
( look for maven assembly plugin )

Comment: For the lazy: `mkdir -p src/{main,test}/{java,resources}`

Comment: More in details here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I have a question. Why does Maven creates the `main` sub folder ? Why not simply `src/java` and `src/resources` ?

Comment: Just a long established convention.   And we have separate source trees for tests and  production code

Answer (score 8):

**src/com.enterprise_name.project_name.** Main.java (the main class)

**src/com.enterprise_name.project_name.model.**(here all model classes)

**src/com.enterprise_name.project_name.view.**(here all view classes, JFrame, Jdialog,etc)

**src/com.enterprise_name.project_name.view.resources.**(here all the files and  images used in the views ***note**)

**src/com.enterprise_name.project_name.controller.**(here all controller classes)

**lib/**(here all the external libraries - dont forget add to build path)

***note** if you need some resource file (xml, config file, etc) create a package .resources. in the specific place where do you need (model, controller, view)

Answer (score 6):

A commonly used structure is the following:

- src - contains all your source files, and possibly the following as well (might be far down the folder tree):
- resources - contains resources such as properties files
- config - everything config related
- lib - a folder containing a your libraries, possibly placed in separate subfolderrs
- bin - contains compiled classes

Answer (score 5):

As far I as know, there is no such thing as a standard project structure for Java per se. However, various tools and IDEs (such as Eclipse) do have a standard structure.

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), a build tool for Java, on the other hand has a very clearly defined (default) project structure. There, all Java source files are placed in the `src/main/java` folder and all resource files (like your config files) are placed in `src/main/resources`.

Here's a very quick introduction to Maven, if you don't know it yet: [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

---

Regarding your question about packaging with dependencies, here is a snipped from one of my Maven POM files that uses the [Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create a JAR file with all dependencies included:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>...</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```